# How can I extract the original String from a formatted one?

Tags: java

Ok so, let's say I have a variable `teamName = apple` and `teamPattern = [MW3-%s]`, which gives me the `full name: [MW3-apple]`.. If I know the **fullName** and **teamPattern** is there any way to get the original ***teamName*** back?

Here's my Java code I used. (This is not a XY problem, *I have to* save it this way -_-)

```java
public String generateFullName(){ // Generate the name
        String teamPattern =  "[MW3-%s]";
        String teamName = "apple";
        return teamPattern.formatted(teamName); // <- Gets saved on a remote location
}
 
public String extractTeamName(String fullName, String teamPattern) {
    //return ? 
}
```

I tried using Java sub-strings but that didn't work out since `patternName` can be set to anything. (I heard of something along the lines of patterns/Regex, but didn't find any useful function)

Comment: Include the relevant part of your code in the question itself instead of an external link.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `teamPattern` contains a single `%s` placeholder? In this case, I'd split it in the part before and after the `%s`, and remove those parts from `fullName`. That can already get tricky if `teamPattern` may contain a(n escaped) literal `%s`.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. You need to scan the team pattern for tokens, each one being one of a literal and a placeholder. You'll have something like `[MW3-`,`%s`,`]`. Then you need to match the literal tokens, and parse the placeholders to their resolved strings.

Answer (score 2):

How much is guaranteed about teamPattern?

If you can be sure that teamPattern will contain exactly one formatting pattern, which will be %s, you can:

- locate the %s within teamPattern  (starts at character #index)
- calculate the amount of text right of the embedded teamName (subtracting)
- calculate the length of the teamName (subtracting)
- take fullName.substring(...)

Comment: This is pretty much it. Basically `teamPattern.substring(teamPattern.indexof("-")+1, teamPattern.length())`?

Answer (score 2):

In general, the backwards-conversion does not yield a unique result. Take, for example, the pattern `"foo-%s-%s"` and the result `"foo-bar-baz-bang"`. We could have arrived here by:

- either replacing the first `"%s"` with `"bar-baz"` and the second `"%s"` with `"bang"`
- or replacing the first `"%s"` with `"bar"` and the second `"%s"` with `"baz-bang"`.

[<kbd>`Ideone.com` demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/SqAXJg)

---

For the concrete pattern `"[MW3-%s]"`, we can create a regex extractor that extracts the original `teamName`:

```
^full name: \[MW3-(?<teamName>.*)]$
```

[<kbd>`regex101.com` demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/0LVRBI/1)

Here is an example on how to use the regular expression to extract the team name:

```
String teamPattern = "[MW3-%s]";
String teamName = "apple";
String fullNamePattern = "full name: " + teamPattern;
String fullName = String.format(fullNamePattern, teamName);
Pattern teamExtractorPattern = Pattern.compile("^full name: \\[MW3-(?<teamName>.*)]$");
Matcher matcher = teamExtractorPattern.matcher(fullName);
if (matcher.matches()) {
  String extractedTeamName = matcher.group("teamName");
  System.out.println(extractedTeamName);
}
```

[<kbd>`Ideone.com` demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/6uAcDr)

---

We can start making the pattern more generic by e.g. replacing `full name :` by `.*`. We could even try to construct the `Pattern` from `teamPattern`, but this requires some special attention (e.g. the `"["` and `"-"` need to be replaced with `"\\\\["` and `"\\\\-"`).

Note that this kind of pattern will stop to function if a line has more than one `]` after the initial `full name: [`-part (due to the greedy nature of regex's `*`, if we make it non-greedy, there are other corner cases to consider). This kind of issue would be preventable if we, for example, knew or could assure (not [assume (`urbandictionary.com`)](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Assume)) that the `teamName` consists of only letters and digits. In this case, we could change the regex to:

```
^full name: \[MW3-(?<teamName>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)]$
```

[<kbd>`regex101.com` demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/H3Rdus/1)

If we also allow `"_"` in `teamName`s, the regular expression simplifies even further:

```
^full name: \[MW3-(?<teamName>\w*)]$
```

[<kbd>`regex101.com` demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/wMQAsG/1)